# Tornado app halting regularly for few seconds with 100% CPU

Tags: amazon-ec2, tornado

I am trying to troubleshoot an app running on tornado 2.4 on Ubuntu 11.04 on EC2. It appears to be hitting 100% CPU regularly and halts at that request for few seconds.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

**Symptoms:**

- top shows 100% cpu just at the time it halts. Normally server is about 30-60% cpu utilization.
- It halts every 2-5 minutes just for one request. I have checked that there are no cronjobs affecting this.
- It halts for about 2 to 9 seconds. Problem goes away on restarting tornado and worsens with tornado uptime. Longer the server is up, for longer duration it halts.
- Http requests for which the problem appears do not seem to have any pattern.
- Interestingly, next request in log sometimes sometimes matches the halting duration and some times does not. Example:

> ```
> 00:00:00      GET /some/request ()
> 00:00:09      GET /next/request (9000ms)
>
> 00:00:00     GET /some/request ()
> 00:00:09     GET /next/request (1ms)
> # 9 seconds gap in requests is certainly not possible as clients are constantly polling.
> ```

- Database (mongodb) shows no expensive or large number of queries. No page faults. Database is on the same machine - local disk.
- vmstat shows no change in read/write sizes compared to last few minutes.
- tornado is running behind nginx.
- sending SIGINT when it was most likely halting, gives different stacktrace everytime. Some of them are below:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "chat/main.py", line 3396, in <module>
>     main()
>   File "chat/main.py", line 3392, in main
>     tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
>   File "/home/ubuntu/tornado/tornado/ioloop.py", line 515, in start
>     self._run_callback(callback)
>   File "/home/ubuntu/tornado/tornado/ioloop.py", line 370, in _run_callback
>     callback()
>   File "/home/ubuntu/tornado/tornado/stack_context.py", line 216, in wrapped
>     callback(*args, **kwargs)
>   File "/home/ubuntu/tornado/tornado/iostream.py", line 303, in wrapper
>     callback(*args)
>   File "/home/ubuntu/tornado/tornado/stack_context.py", line 216, in wrapped
>     callback(*args, **kwargs)
>   File "/home/ubuntu/tornado/tornado/httpserver.py", line 298, in _on_request_body
>     self.request_callback(self._request)
>   File "/home/ubuntu/tornado/tornado/web.py", line 1421, in __call__
>     handler = spec.handler_class(self, request, **spec.kwargs)
>   File "/home/ubuntu/tornado/tornado/web.py", line 126, in __init__
>     application.ui_modules.iteritems())
>   File "/home/ubuntu/tornado/tornado/web.py", line 125, in <genexpr>
>     self.ui["_modules"] = ObjectDict((n, self._ui_module(n, m)) for n, m in
>   File "/home/ubuntu/tornado/tornado/web.py", line 1114, in _ui_module
>     def _ui_module(self, name, module):
> KeyboardInterrupt
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "chat/main.py", line 3398, in <module>
>     main()
>   File "chat/main.py", line 3394, in main
>     tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
>   File "/home/ubuntu/tornado/tornado/ioloop.py", line 515, in start
>     self._run_callback(callback)
>   File "/home/ubuntu/tornado/tornado/ioloop.py", line 370, in _run_callback
>     callback()
>   File "/home/ubuntu/tornado/tornado/stack_context.py", line 216, in wrapped
>     callback(*args, **kwargs)
>   File "/home/ubuntu/tornado/tornado/iostream.py", line 303, in wrapper
>     callback(*args)
>   File "/home/ubuntu/tornado/tornado/stack_context.py", line 216, in wrapped
>     callback(*args, **kwargs)
>   File "/home/ubuntu/tornado/tornado/httpserver.py", line 285, in _on_headers
>     self.request_callback(self._request)
>   File "/home/ubuntu/tornado/tornado/web.py", line 1408, in __call__
>     transforms = [t(request) for t in self.transforms]
>   File "/home/ubuntu/tornado/tornado/web.py", line 1811, in __init__
>     def __init__(self, request):
> KeyboardInterrupt
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "chat/main.py", line 3351, in <module>
>     main()
>   File "chat/main.py", line 3347, in main
>     tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
>   File "/home/ubuntu/tornado/tornado/ioloop.py", line 571, in start
>     self._handlers[fd](fd, events)
>   File "/home/ubuntu/tornado/tornado/stack_context.py", line 216, in wrapped
>     callback(*args, **kwargs)
>   File "/home/ubuntu/tornado/tornado/netutil.py", line 342, in accept_handler
>     callback(connection, address)
>   File "/home/ubuntu/tornado/tornado/netutil.py", line 237, in _handle_connection
>     self.handle_stream(stream, address)
>   File "/home/ubuntu/tornado/tornado/httpserver.py", line 156, in handle_stream
>     self.no_keep_alive, self.xheaders, self.protocol)
>   File "/home/ubuntu/tornado/tornado/httpserver.py", line 183, in __init__
>     self.stream.read_until(b("\r\n\r\n"), self._header_callback)
>   File "/home/ubuntu/tornado/tornado/iostream.py", line 139, in read_until
>     self._try_inline_read()
>   File "/home/ubuntu/tornado/tornado/iostream.py", line 385, in _try_inline_read
>     if self._read_to_buffer() == 0:
>   File "/home/ubuntu/tornado/tornado/iostream.py", line 401, in _read_to_buffer
>     chunk = self.read_from_fd()
>   File "/home/ubuntu/tornado/tornado/iostream.py", line 632, in read_from_fd
>     chunk = self.socket.recv(self.read_chunk_size)
> KeyboardInterrupt
> ```

Any tips on how to troubleshoot this is greatly appreciated.

Further observations:

- strace -p, during the time it hangs, shows empty output.
- ltrace -p during hang time shows *only* free() calls in large numbers:
  free(0x6fa70080)                                                         = 
  free(0x1175f8060)                                                        = 
  free(0x117a5c370)                                                        =

Comment: Is there a chance you registered an PeriodicCallback ? that might block the ioloop if some operation is blocking.

Comment: Do you use a synchronous connection to MongoDB ? on a tcp socket ? If for any reason the DB or network hangs it will block the ioloop.

Comment: Does the hang really appears every 5mn ? In this case I would favor the db connection block (check MongoDB logs for service times >1s). Otherwise my experience with EC2 and a similar stack (tornado+redis) is that once or twice a day a similar hang appears for a few seconds, and seems to be related to SYN flood attacks. Is your box port 80 open ? check `dmesg` for any hints on this type of attacks.

Comment: @oDDsKooL Thanks for your comments! No PeriodicCallback. There are sync calls to mongodb, I am sure that is not the cause. DB profile shows no expensive or large number of queries. Rarely page faults. Query rate is hardly 5/sec.

Comment: Added few more observations (ltrace and strace outputs from hang). Seems to suggest a memory leak. The hang regularly happens - anywhere between 2-5 mins. Hang duration increases longer the server has been up (2secs - 9secs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're suffering from garbage collection (GC) storms.  The behavior you've described is typical of that diagnosis, and the *ltrace* further supports the hypothesis.

Lots of objects are being allocated and disposed of in the main/event loops being exercised by your usage ... and the periodic flurries of calls to *free()* result from that.

One possible approach would be to profile your code (or libraries on which you are depending) and see if you can refactor it to use (and re-use) objects from pre-allocated pools.

Another possible mitigation would be to make your own, more frequent, calls to trigger the garbage collection --- more expensive in aggregate but possibly less costly at each call.  (That would be a trade-off for more predictable throughput).

You might be able to use the [Python: gc module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html) both for investigating the issue more deeply (using **gc.set_debug()**) and for a simple attempted mitigation (calls to **gc.collect()** after each transaction for example).  You might also try running your application with **gc.disable()** for a reasonable length of time to see if further implicates the Python garbage collector.  Note that disabling the garbage collector for an extended period of time will almost certainly cause paging/swapping ... so use it only for validation of our hypothesis and don't expect that to solve the problem in any meaningful way.  It may just defer the problem 'til the whole system is thrashing and needs to be rebooted.

Here's an example of using **gc.collect()** in another SO thread on Tornado: [SO: Tornado memory leak on dropped connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626064/tornado-memory-leak-on-dropped-connections)